# Что делать с кнопкой "restart"?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
//configuration
let clicks = 0;

const TIMEOUT = 10000;
const display = document.querySelector('#display');
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
const counter = `введите сюда код`
document.querySelector('#counter');
const stArt = document.querySelector('#start');

//start
button.onclick = start;

stArt.textContent = 'Press to Start!';

function start() {
  stArt.textContent = null;
  const startTime = Date.now();

  display.textContent = TIMEOUT + ' mS';

  button.onclick = () => counter.textContent = (clicks++) + 2 + ' clicks';

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const delta = Date.now() - startTime;
    display.textContent = (TIMEOUT - delta) + ' mS';
  }, 150);
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    stArt.textContent = null;
    button.onclick = null;
    display.textContent = 'GAME OVER';
    clearInterval(interval);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, TIMEOUT);
};

//restart
const restart = document.querySelector('#restart');
restart.onclick = () => {
  display.textContent = null;
  counter.textContent = null;
  stArt.textContent = 'Press to Start!';

  clicks = 0;
  button.onclick = start;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style no2.css">
  <title>clicker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="bestresult"></div>

    <div id="start"></div>

    <div id="display"></div>

    <div id="counter"></div>

    <button id="button"></button>

    <button id="restart">restart</button>
  </main>

  <script src="clicker.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Проблема в кнопке `restart`. При нажатии на неё таймер, не обнулившись, продолжает свой ход, а поверх него создаётся новый. Я пытался сделать появление кнопки restart через 10 секунд, пробовал обнулять значение `TIMEOUT` (`TIMEOUT = null;`, `TIMEOUT = timeout;` и `TIMEOUT = setTimeout;`).

Конечно, сложно вот так понять всё, что я здесь написал, вот так сразу, однако это скорее крик души, ведь я такую незначительную проблему не могу решить уже 2 день. В общем, если вы что-то поняли, то прошу помочь.

Comment: "а поверх него создаётся новый" - не создаётся

Comment: не понял?=-=-=-

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку restart новый таймер не создаётся.

Comment: ой так да.. забыл добавить, что я перезапускаю игру в то время, пока другая не закончилась.

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема не в TIMEOUT, а в interval, его нужно сделать глобальным и проверять кнопкой restart существует ли он уже.

```
let started = false;

const start = () => {
//Запускаем таймер
}

const stop = () => {
//Выключаем таймер и обнуляем значения
}

button.onlick = () => {
  if (!started) {
  start()
  } else {
  stop()
  }
}
```

Дальше сами ;)